# uniqueness with nested_form_for rails is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have models Vehicle, Tag, VehicleTag

```
class VehicleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :vehicle_id, :tag_id, :capacity

  belongs_to :vehicle
  belongs_to :tag

  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, :scope => [:vehicle_id]
end
```

and I have used 'nested_form_for' to enter value in vehicle_tags tables but   validates_uniqueness_of is not working when user select same tags multiple times and its saving data in tables.

But when I have a single record in vehicle_tag with tag_id=2, vehicle_id=24 and when user select same tag again this time its thronging uniqueness validation. as I am getting first time we don't have value in DB and second time we have.

But I want to through uniqueness when user select multiple same tag.

EDIT: vehicle_tag table structure:

```
+-----+------------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | vehicle_id | tag_id | capacity | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 241 |          2 |      2 |        2 | 2014-04-22 11:35:11 | 2014-04-22 11:35:11 |
| 242 |          2 |      2 |        3 | 2014-04-22 11:35:11 | 2014-04-22 11:35:11 |
+-----+------------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicle_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :vehicle_tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle_tags, :reject_if => proc { |a| a['capacity'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicle_tags
  has_many :vehicles, :through => :vehicle_tags
end
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample record of your table?

Comment: @Pavan, Vehicle table has attributes: id, name (Ex: byke, car)
and Tag table has attributes: id, name (Ex: women, men )

Comment: I mean can you a post a sample record of your `vehicle_tag` table with values.

Comment: @Pavan please see data in question

Comment: can you post your `vehicle` and `tag` models?

Comment: @Pavan I have posted it

Comment: Do you have this `add_index :vehicle_tags, [:tag_id, :vehicle_id], :unique => true` in your `vehicle_tags` migration file?

Comment: @Pavan what will happen with this

Answer (score 0):

you may try this, as in a seperate line

```
validates :tag_id, :uniqueness => true
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html):

Concurrency and integrity:

Using this validation method in conjunction with ActiveRecord::Validations#save does not guarantee the absence of duplicate record insertions, because uniqueness checks on the application level are inherently prone to race conditions.

...

The best way to work around this problem is to add a unique index to the database table using ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#add_index. In the rare case that a race condition occurs, the database will guarantee the field's uniqueness.

Generate a new migration to add the index with the following:

```
add_index(:vehicle_tags, [:vehicle_id, :tag_id], unique: true)
```

Comment: Ohh,i was too late to answer. :(

Comment: I am getting Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '6-1' for key 'index_vehicle_tags_on_vehicle_id_and_tag_id': INSERT INTO `vehicle_tags` (`capacity`, `created_at`, `tag_id`, `updated_at`, `vehicle_id`) VALUES (1, '2014-04-22 12:37:15', 1, '2014-04-22 12:37:15', 6

Comment: Did you remove uniqueness validation from your model?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, add this line to your `vehicle_tags` migration file.

```
add_index :vehicle_tags, [:tag_id, :vehicle_id], :unique => true in your vehicle_tags
```

***what will happen with this?***

It will make sure you have unique `vehicle/tag` pairs in your `vehicle_tags` table.

Comment: @Rubyonrailsdeveloper right now you are not getting eror messages?

Comment: yes getting mysql exception  Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '6-1' for key 'index_vehicle_tags_on_vehicle_id_and_tag_id': INSERT INTO vehicle_tags (capacity, created_at, tag_id, updated_at, vehicle_id) VALUES (1, '2014-04-22 12:37:15', 1, '2014-04-22 12:37:15', 6

Comment: @Rubyonrailsdeveloper Try deleting all your records in `vehicle_tags` table and try adding again.

Comment: I think uniq index on database is through an error which avoiding the rule

Comment: @Rubyonrailsdeveloper No! ok delete all your records in `vehicle` and `tags` tables also and try inserting them again

Comment: I can not delete valuable records